# onClickListener not letting onFling trigger

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onfling

I have both an `onClickListener` and an `onFling` (using `GestureDetector`).

If I click on the button the `onClickListener` fires.

If I fling on the body of the screen then `onFling` fires.

However if I start the fling from the button, then neither fire.

Layout as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/myButton"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the code looks like:

```
public class myLayout extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    private GestureDetector gDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);

        gDetector = new GestureDetector(getBaseContext(), this);
        findViewById(R.id.myButton).setOnClickListener(button_OnClickListener);
    }

    final View.OnClickListener button_OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(final View buttonView) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent2, float v, float v2) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float v, float v2) {
        if (start.getRawY() < finish.getRawY()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fling detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
        Log.i("Touch", "onTouchEvent");
        return gDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
    }
}
```

**How can I get the `onFling` to be run first?**

I have looked at other posts for this (e.g. [onClick blocking onFling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115032/onclick-blocking-onfling)) but not found a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [`onInterceptTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) (or, maybe [`dispatchTouchEvent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29), at this point I'm not sure which will suit better) of the `Button`'s parent (or something even higher in hierarchy) to decide whether to route the touch to the button or the gesture detector.

If the `MotionEvent`'s coordinates belong to the `Button`'s rect and `ACTION_DOWN` is followed by `ACTION_UP` shortly, it's a click and should be routed to the `Button`, but if you receive `ACTION_MOVE` and the movement continues to the extent where you know it's a swipe - it should be handled by gesture detector.

**UPD** Here's an answer which explains the technique https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834952/375929

Comment: Thanks - that post certainly helps. Sorry for late response

Comment: Also found a very useful answer at the following link which shows how to include the `onInterceptTouchEvent` within a `ViewGroup` and how to link a layout to this `ViewGroup`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367983/how-to-use-viewgroup-in-android